# Find a type of Device (It's android or iPhone) from device token using PHP

Tags: php, android, iphone, cakephp-1.2

I am working on a PHP application, the mobile app requests to PHP app for some service. The mobile app is sending a device token to server. So I want to find out what mobile OS the request is coming from? It's android or iPhone?

Comment: You can get Device model and send...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only separate android and iphone, add to request parameter `&os=android` in android's code and `&os=iphone` in iPhone's code.

Add: Also you can used the `$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Comment: yes that i know, but we can't make changes it now. Is their another solution ? I want to do it at server side.

Comment: What is you receive in 'User-Agent'?

Comment: what in $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?

Comment: hey I got the solution, same as you mention above, I used the $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'] for geting type of device